# Android GPS tracks wrong location

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

In my app I want to show user's current location and if location is changed it will show an alert message to change the location. The problem is that it shows location chahnge message even when the phone's GPS is off. What might be the reason?

Here's my code:

```
 protected void onResume() {

    /**
     * get saved Location from shared preference
     * 
     */

    SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity_Home.this);
    String getL = sPrefs.getString(Utility.KEY_USER_LAT, "0.000000");
    String getLo = sPrefs.getString(Utility.KEY_USER_LONG, "0.000000");
    getLat = Double.parseDouble(getL);
    getLog = Double.parseDouble(getLo);
    gps = new GpsTracker(Activity_Home.this);

    /**
     * Get user current latitude and longitude and match them to stored
     * latitude and longitude if distance between these latitude then Pop up
     * will be show
     * 
     * @author Ankit
     */

    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        System.out.println("Latitude is " + getLat);

        if (getLat > 0.0) {
            Location locationA = new Location("point A");
            locationA.setLatitude(getLat);
            locationA.setLongitude(getLog);
            Location locationB = new Location("point B");
            locationB.setLatitude(latitude);
            locationB.setLongitude(longitude);
            distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

            // Toast.makeText(Activity_Home.this,
            // "Distance is :"+Double.toString(distance),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            distance = distance / 1000000;
            int getDistance = (int) (distance * 1000000);

            System.out.println("Distance is " + getDistance);
            if (getDistance > 100) {
                showWarningMessage();
            }
        }
        String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String lon = String.valueOf(longitude);
        SharedPreferences sPref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity_Home.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit = sPref.edit();
        sEdit.putString(Utility.KEY_USER_LAT, lat);
        sEdit.putString(Utility.KEY_USER_LONG, lon);
        sEdit.commit();
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }


    super.onResume();
}
// Method for show an Alert dialog for user if user's location changed''

public void showWarningMessage() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Activity_Home.this);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Location Changed");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("It seems your location has changed, would you like to change the Branch now?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Home.this,
                            Activity_Settings.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}




public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 100; // 100 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GpsTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        System.out.println("=====isGPSEnabled: 
 "+isGPSEnabled+"====isNetworkEnabled: "+isNetworkEnabled);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            System.out.println("=====notgps");
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager

.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager

 .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GpsTracker.this);
    }      
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Enable GPS");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to 
 settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new 
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new   
 Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new   
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
   // alertDialog.;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Ugh, not GPSTracker.... Don't use this code.... See here: http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Comment: if you want to have location when it is changed use `onLocationChanged(Location location)`

Comment: locationA.setLatitude(getLat);,   locationA.setLongitude(getLog); will these two lines get the current location when GPS is off? Or it will simply return 0?

Comment: @HariKrishnan locationA.setLatitude(getLat);, locationA.setLongitude(getLog); will return the last location saved in shared pref

Comment: I've same issue .Gps tracker shows me wrong lat long . I am also trying to fix this bug .

Answer (score 0):

Here is one sample code for find location check this if it works for you

public static void LocationFind() {

```
    try {
        if (Skyhook) {
            _xps.getXPSLocation(null,
                    // note we convert _period to seconds
                    (int) (_period / 1000), _desiredXpsAccuracy, _callback);
            // _xps.getLocation(null, _streetAddressLookup, _callback);
        } else {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
                // Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    lastknownlocations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (lastknownlocations != null) {
                        lat = lastknownlocations.getLatitude();
                        lng = lastknownlocations.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
                // Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    lastknownlocations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (lastknownlocations != null) {
                        lat = lastknownlocations.getLatitude();
                        lng = lastknownlocations.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (lat == 0.0 && lng == 0.0) {
                lng = lastknownlocations.getLongitude();
                lat = lastknownlocations.getLatitude();
            }

            getAddressFromLatLong(lat, lng);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out with this service class. This sends updates to method `sendLocationDataToProcess(Location location)` whenever there is a different of `10 meters` with respect to last location

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener{

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Context appContext;
    private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
    private int mInterval=0;
    private final int CONNTIMEOUT=50000;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        appContext=getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
            currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
            startTracking();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }   
    private void startTracking() {

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG, "ConnectionResult SUCCESS");
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }else{
                Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG, "NOT connected googleApiClient.connect()");
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public AppLocationService() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG,"onConnected");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(mInterval * 1000); // milliseconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(mInterval * 1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES);//dostance change
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionCheck!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG,"onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG, "onLocationChanged position: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + " accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());
        Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG, "onLocationChanged position: location.getAccuracy()= "+location.getAccuracy());
        sendLocationDataToProcess(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v(Constants.BLL_LOG,"onConnectionFailed");
    }

    void sendLocationDataToProcess(Location location){
        //Do your logic with Location data
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }       
    }
```